# Removing lines that intersect with other within the same layer

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, intersection

This may be very simple, but I have a line feature class in ArcGIS and I want to remove all the lines that intersect other lines in the feature class. So in the example below, I would like to remove lines #2-4 and keep 1.
Any thoughts/ideas?

[image: Map with 4 lines of the transects layer]

EDIT: I may have found a workaround, but there's gotta be a simpler way. My workaround:
`Buffer` around the lines with minimal distance -->  `Count overlapping features` for the buffers --> remove those with more than 2 overlaps --> Run `Near` with the lines and the reduced buffer polygons --> export only those with NEAR_DIST=-1 (that means the lines that are not near any intersection). So the code would look like this:

```
arcpy.analysis.Buffer("transects", r"***.gdb\transects_Buffer", "2 Meters", "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", None, "PLANAR") # Create buffer polygons
arcpy.analysis.CountOverlappingFeatures("transects_Buffer;transects_Buffer", r"***.gdb\transects_Buffer_C_overlap", 2, None) # Find the buffer polygons that overlap
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("transects_Buffer_C_overlap", "NEW_SELECTION", "COUNT_ > 2", "INVERT") # Select only those that overlap with other polygons, so COUNT_ > 2
arcpy.management.DeleteRows("transects_Buffer_C_overlap") # Delete all the other buffer polygons
arcpy.analysis.Near("transects", "transects_Buffer_C_overlap", "2 Meters", "NO_LOCATION", "NO_ANGLE", "PLANAR", "NEAR_FID NEAR_FID;NEAR_DIST NEAR_DIST") # Find the lines that are near the overlapping buffer polygons
arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute("transects", "NEW_SELECTION", "NEAR_DIST = -1", None) # Select only the lines that are near overlapping polygons
arcpy.management.CopyFeatures("transects", r"***.gdb\transects_no_intersect", '', None, None, None) # Export those lines to a new feature class that holds only line that do not intersect.
```

Comment: The definition of "remove" in this context is unclear. And what happens if 2 overlaps 3,4 and 3 overlaps 2,4 and 4 overlaps 2,3 -- Do all three get deleted? Any way you solve this is going to depend on creating only-feature-N and not-N layers, then selecting by intersection. What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Vince Good point. Thanks for forcing me to be more specific.
Let's say I want a new layer that contains only the lines that do not intersect other lines at all. I.e., remove ALL lines that intersect - 2, 3, AND 4 in the example above.

Comment: New **layer** or new **feature class**?  Please [Edit] the Question so that folks don't need to mine comments.

Comment: Sorry, new feature class. Edited. Thanks again.

Comment: @SonofaBeach I edited the question. I wanted to remove ALL lines that intersect other lines. So leave only #1.

Comment: Other needed edits: How many features are involved? Have you attempted anything manually? This looks like it's headed to a script -- Have you tried poking in ArcPy on this? What do you have so far?

Comment: @Vince I edited with a workaround I found. There must be an easier way but maybe my edit clarifies the question better.

Comment: +1. You can reduce workflow to 2 tools. Near on itself with 0 search radius and Select with near_fid = -1.

Comment: @FelixIP Thanks, that's a great point.